# Contact form 7 (версия 4.9) не работает ajax, после отправки перезагружается страница

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form7

Contact Form 7 (версия 4.9)

Шаблон не стандартный (отключен jqery wordpress)

Использую jQuery 3.2.1

scripts.js контактной формы подключен вручную

**После отправки формы страница перезагружается**

```
$.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
            '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/feedback' ),
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
        ajaxSuccess( data, status, xhr, $form );
        $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).attr('action', '#').removeClass( 'is-active' );
    } ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ) {
        var $e = $( '<div class="ajax-error"></div>' ).text( error.message );
        $form.after( $e );
    } );
```

Comment: В версиях 4.8 и 4.9 плагина есть какой-то конфликт скриптов. Попробуйте поставить 4.7, уберите все, что вы тут накрутили - должно работать. А вообще вопрос странный - непонятно, зачем вы все так активно ломали.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Было подозрение на отключенный REST API (в моем случае он тоже не нужен хоть и большинство плагинов его используют) после так и не заработал адекватно. Формулировка "ламать" в моем случаи скорее не уместна так как я оптимизируюсь сайт (сжатие, асинхронная загрузка и тд). С 4.7 проблем не было и таки вернулся на старую версию.

Comment: Благодарен больше за внимание к моему вопросу чем к помощи в решении так как вопрос по прежнему не решен.

Comment: Еще в 4.7 используется дополнительный скрипт form в котором проще вызывать форму и больше хуков в гугле.

Comment: Уберите jQuery 3.2.1 и уберите свой скрипт. Поставьте 4.7 - должно работать

Answer (score 1):

правильное решение - убрать код, отключающий rest api - зайти в постоянные ссылки и нажать на "сохранить изменения". и все будет работать.

Comment: нет. Вы внимательно читали задачу? и причем здесь постоянные ссылки?

Comment: если вы не в курсе того, что отключенный rest api нельзя обратно включить без обновления постоянных ссылок - это ваша проблема.

Comment: самый лучший совет - это отключение rest api :)